# TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, theano

I'm trying to use scikit-learn in conjunction with Keras (Theano backend) in order to optimize some hyperparameters of my neural network, however I keep getting the same error (as stated in the title). I'm not sure how to get around it. Here is my code for importing the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Vikram\OneDrive\Documents\Videos\Documents\PERTH-USD_JPY_D.csv')
print(df.head())
```

Code for changing the backend to Theano:

```
import theano
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
import keras
# Using Theano backend.
```

Preliminary stuff:

```
from keras import regularizers
from keras import layers
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

Defining inputs and output:

```
X = df[['Ask High', 'Bid Low', 'Ask Low', 'Bid Average', 'Ask Average']]
X = X.values

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
feature_mtx = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(X.shape)


y = df[['Bid High']]
y=y.values
y=y.ravel()
print(y.shape)
```

Split into training and testing data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=4) 

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
print ('Train set:', X_train.shape, y_train.shape) 
print ('Test set:', X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
```

Reshaping inputs to 3D vectors for compatibility with LSTM:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

Build the neural network:

```
def model_build(rate=0.1, max_value=3):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.LSTM(180, activation='tanh', input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(layers.LSTM(100, activation='tanh', bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
  model.add(layers.LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
  model.add(layers.Dense(100, kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(max_value=3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation='linear'))

  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
  return model
```

Use KerasRegressor wrapper for scikit-learn:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
model_2 = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_build, epochs=3, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

Hyperparameter optimization algorithm:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
max_value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rate = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
param_grid = dict(max_value=max_value, rate=rate)
rand=RandomizedSearchCV(model_2, param_grid, cv=3)
rand.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (rand.best_score_, rand.best_params_))
yhat=rand.predict(X_test)
```

Regression metric:

```
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
expvar=explained_variance_score(y_test, yhat, multioutput='uniform average')
print(expvar)
```

And this is my error where `yhat` is defined:

```
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

EDIT:
Here is the full traceback for the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-5f9c97171748>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Vikram/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vikram/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Vikram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Vikram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Vikram/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 71, in <module>
    yhat=rand.predict(X_test)

  File "C:\Users\Vikram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 116, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Comment: On what line does your code error. I'd assume it's your `yhat` variable. But the code looks syntactically correct. However, your variable `X_test` is nowhere else in this code.

Comment: Yes the error is occurring where the ```yhat``` variable is placed.

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: I have edited the post and included the full traceback.